# Drupal Theming Homepage

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to theme a Drupal site.
From what I was reading, if I have page--front.tpl.php, it should work for the homepage.
However, it doesn't seem to work for me.

From themer info, it is suggesting the file name to be page--node--6.tpl.php, which works, but I don't want to hardcode the id number.

Also $is_front is always coming back false.

For this node, I created a "Page" content type and select "bring it to front" and also set in site information for this node, which I alias to "Home" to be the default page.

Still not working. What am I missing?

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have in page info

Default front page: node/6

then you could use page--front.tpl.php to theme the node as the front page, it must work.

- Check you have the page--front.tpl.php in the correct place, in the
  theme folder of the active theme.
- Flush caches.

Comment: Not the solution but this point me to the right direction. I had Default page set to "home", which is an alias of node/6. Making it node/6 works wonder.